Brand new iPad (10th generation) apparently has a 10 year old battery? Is this even possible?
I just got this iPad (10th generation) 3 days ago from a certified apple reseller and when I plugged it into my Mac to check the battery with an app I found out that apparently it was manufactured in 2014?
Is this even possible or is it an error? I'd get it if it was 2-3 years old but 10 seems quite a lot.


coconutBattery has a 10 year problem with at least some newish batteries. It says the battery in my M3 MBP was manufactured 2013-06-24. But ok with my iPhone 13.

There might be a couple of reasons for this strange date.
Old batch of batteries used in manufacture
It might be possible that even though the battery was manufactured in 2014, it was never used and only put into the iPad (as new) when the iPad came off the assembly line. Maybe there was some "old" new stock of batteries that were used for that particular batch of iPads, possibly due to supply shortages or logical issues.
However, given the high turnover of parts in the rapid manufacture of Apple devices, this does seem unlikely, I must admit.
A bug in coconutBattery
It seems more likely that it is just a bug in coconutBattery itself, as gilby has pointed out in their comment:

coconutBattery has a 10 year problem with at least some newish batteries.

coconutBattery doesn't seem to be particularly reliable, and there are a number of people with issues similar to yours:

From this post on Why does coconutBattery say that my Mac is already 7 months when in a fact I bought this 13" MacBook Air just last August 4? This is somewhat disappointing.:

Coconut Battery uses the coding contained witin the serial number to establish an incept date.
When a new model Mac is released, it takes some time for a revision release of Coconut Battery to correctly read your serial number. Hang tight, I'm sure the next revision will reveal an accurate date.


From Coconutbattery + Big Sur - wrong battery age:

I have a mid 2014 MBP. I installed a new battery. With Mojave Coconutbattery said my new battery was made in 2022. I then upgraded to Big Sur. Now it says the battery was made in march 2015.



Summary
I wouldn't worry too much, it's probably just coconutBattery being weird. So long as the iPad works, and the version of the actual board inside is as it should be, that is the main thing.
It's easy to change a battery, they are just consumables, after all.

this makes a lot of sense thank you for taking the time to explain everything!


I just got this iPad (10th generation) 3 days ago from a certified apple reseller…

“Certified Apple Reseller” means nothing when the reseller is unscrupulous.  Since the 10th Gen iPad was made in 2022, the only way you can have a battery dated 8 years prior to the devices manufactured year is if it was opened up and swapped out (for whatever reason).

and when I plugged it into my Mac to check the battery with an app…

It’s obvious you didn’t trust this reseller and suspected tampering with the battery. There’s no reason to check these things unless you’ve got a “bad feeling” about things.
These are expensive devices to begin with and the incentive is high to pull some shenanigans to extend a profit where they can.  Personally, I buy new, but if I’m looking at a preowned device, I won’t purchase unless there’s at least 50% discount.  To me, the risk is too great
I would return it for a refund.

i did buy the ipad new, it wasn't preowned, that's why i was curious of supposed 10 year old battery. there are no official apple stores in my country, only resellers (like istyle, where i got the ipad from). as for me checking the battery, it wasn't because of a bad feeling, i just wanted to keep track of how the battery degrades over time since coconutbattery keeps track of every time i check a device. thank you for your response though!

+1 as it certainly is possible, although I'm not convinced (depends upon the country I suppose, as well as other factors - like maybe the seller had got hold of a new but damaged iPad). It seems a lot of work to go to, just to save a few dollars (which is the price of a after-market battery). Also, depending upon the workmanship, it might be noticeable that the factory glue had been softened and replaced around the screen.
